# npm post install script does not work with sudo

Tags: node.js, npm

I need to run a post-install script because a library I am using (`elastic.js`) is not bundled correctly.

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "xxxxxxx",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "elastic.js": "fullscale/elastic.js"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "install": "cp node_modules/elastic.js/dist/elastic.js node_modules/elastic.js"
    }
}
```

When in `npm install` this on my development machine, it works.

On my production machine, however, all application files are owned by root. When I run `sudo npm install` there, then the folder `node_modules` interestingly doesn't belong to `root` but to my own user that runs the `sudo` command. Subsequently the install script fails:

`npm WARN cannot run in wd xxxxxxx@1.0.0 cp node_modules/elastic.js/dist/elastic.js node_modules/elastic.js (wd=/usr/share/xxxxxxx/app)`

But when I issue this exact command it works, both as my user and as `root`.

So here's the question(s): Why is the directory `node_modules` not owned by `root`? And how can I make this post-install script work? Is there a better way to overcome the badly packaged module?

Comment: Could you post the link to the `elastic.js` repo?

Comment: Sure, it's https://github.com/fullscale/elastic.js